# Why does Golang yaml.v2 turn my struct into a map when I construct it via reflection?

Tags: go, struct, reflection, types, yaml

I'm working on a generic config parser that reads a YAML config file and stores the result in a struct. I'd like for the parser to be type agnostic, and I want to implement some override logic, so I'm using reflection.

Below is a complete but very simplified version of what I'm working on, which illustrates the problem around the call to yaml.Unmarshal. If I pass in a pointer to a struct that I created without reflection (`base2 := TestConf{}` in the example code), it works as expected: a strongly-typed struct goes in, and a strongly-typed struct comes out.

However, if I pass in a struct that I create with reflection (`base := reflect.New(configType).Elem().Interface()` in the example code), I pass in a struct and get a `map[interface{}]interface{}` back. As you can see, I've done my best to verify that the two structs are identical, panicking if their types are different or if they're not DeepEqual.

This is giving me a real headache at present, but I can work around it. I'd just like to understand why it's happening, and perhaps learn a way around it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "time"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type TestConf struct {
    RequiredConfig `yaml:"RequiredConfig"`
    Str1           string     `yaml:"Str1"`
    Strptr1        *string    `yaml:"Strptr1"`
    TimePtr        *time.Time `yaml:"TimePtr"`
}

type RequiredConfig struct {
    Environment string `yaml:"Environment"`
}

var BaseConfigPath = "./config_test.yml"

func main() {
    conf := TestConf{}
    LoadConfig(&conf)
}

func LoadConfig(target interface{}) {
    targetActual := reflect.ValueOf(target).Elem()
    configType := targetActual.Type()
    base := reflect.New(configType).Elem().Interface()
    base2 := TestConf{}

    if reflect.TypeOf(base) != reflect.TypeOf(base2) {
        panic("your argument is invalid")
    }

    if !reflect.DeepEqual(base, base2) {
        panic("your argument is invalid")
    }

    if _, err := os.Stat(BaseConfigPath); !os.IsNotExist(err) {
        raw, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(BaseConfigPath)

        fmt.Printf("Before base Type: \"%v\", Kind: \"%v\"\n", reflect.TypeOf(base), reflect.ValueOf(base).Kind())
        err = yaml.Unmarshal(raw, &base)
        fmt.Printf("After base Type: \"%v\", Kind: \"%v\"\n", reflect.TypeOf(base), reflect.ValueOf(base).Kind())

        fmt.Printf("Before base2 Type: \"%v\", Kind: \"%v\"\n", reflect.TypeOf(base2), reflect.ValueOf(base2).Kind())
        err = yaml.Unmarshal(raw, &base2)
        fmt.Printf("After base2 Type: \"%v\", Kind: \"%v\"\n", reflect.TypeOf(base2), reflect.ValueOf(base2).Kind())
    }
}
```

To run this, you'll also need this YAML file saved at `./config_test.yml`:

```
RequiredConfig:
  Environment: dev
Str1: String 1
Strptr1: String pointer 1
TimePtr: 2018-08-01T17:25:50.179949-04:00
```

The output I get:

```
Before base Type: "main.TestConf", Kind: "struct"
After base Type: "map[interface {}]interface {}", Kind: "map"
Before base2 Type: "main.TestConf", Kind: "struct"
After base2 Type: "main.TestConf", Kind: "struct"
```

So `base2` acts as expected. `base` somehow gets converted to a map.

Answer (score 2):

That's because this line:

```
base := reflect.New(configType).Elem().Interface()
```

Is literally type interface{} at this point.

If you do this:

```
base, ok := base := reflect.New(configType).Elem().Interface().(TestConf)
if !ok{
    panic("got wrong type")
}
//rest of your code
```

You will get the results you expect.

**Edit to address reply**

Pass the pointer interface umarshal

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "time"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type TestConf struct {
    RequiredConfig `yaml:"RequiredConfig"`
    Str1           string     `yaml:"Str1"`
    Strptr1        *string    `yaml:"Strptr1"`
    TimePtr        *time.Time `yaml:"TimePtr"`
}

type RequiredConfig struct {
    Environment string `yaml:"Environment"`
}

var BaseConfigPath = "./config_test.yml"

func main() {
    conf := TestConf{}
    LoadConfig(&conf)
}

func LoadConfig(target interface{}) {
    targetActual := reflect.ValueOf(target).Elem()
    configType := targetActual.Type()
    baseReflect := reflect.New(configType)
    // Actual type.
    base := baseReflect.Elem().Interface()
    base2 := TestConf{}

    if reflect.TypeOf(base) != reflect.TypeOf(base2) {
        panic("your argument is invalid")
    }

    if !reflect.DeepEqual(base, base2) {
        panic("your argument is invalid")
    }

    if _, err := os.Stat(BaseConfigPath); !os.IsNotExist(err) {
        raw, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(BaseConfigPath)

        fmt.Printf("Before base Type: \"%v\", Kind: \"%v\"\n", reflect.TypeOf(base), reflect.ValueOf(base).Kind())
        // Passes the pointer to unmarshal
        err = yaml.Unmarshal(raw, baseReflect.Interface())
        fmt.Printf("After base Type: \"%v\", Kind: \"%v\"\n", reflect.TypeOf(base), reflect.ValueOf(base).Kind())

        fmt.Printf("Before base2 Type: \"%v\", Kind: \"%v\"\n", reflect.TypeOf(base2), reflect.ValueOf(base2).Kind())
        err = yaml.Unmarshal(raw, &base2)
        fmt.Printf("After base2 Type: \"%v\", Kind: \"%v\"\n", reflect.TypeOf(base2), reflect.ValueOf(base2).Kind())
    }
}
```

Yields:

```
Before base Type: "main.TestConf", Kind: "struct"
After base Type: "main.TestConf", Kind: "struct"
Before base2 Type: "main.TestConf", Kind: "struct"
After base2 Type: "main.TestConf", Kind: "struct"
```

Comment: Thanks! Trouble is, I don't know ahead of time what the type is that is passed in. If I did, I could just instantiate it directly, as I do with base2, above. I just used base2 to illustrate the difference between what works and what doesn't. What I need is a way, via reflection and without explicitly knowing the type, to get an object that is identical to the one I can create directly from a known type. Or at least some understanding of why my created struct is different.

Comment: @JohnSizemore Gotcha. So usually there are two ways to look at this.
1) Make your caller receive the result and cast.
2) Since you already passed in a type pointer the caller knows already what the type is. You can see an example of this in your main func where the type is known there. You can then perform your comparison after the load config call.

Comment: Well, I've tried the casting approach, but Go doesn't allow type assertion with a type variable. It has to be a known type. And the second thing is basically what I'm trying to do: main passes in a struct, and the load func gets the type of that argument and then uses reflection to make a copy (I need to copy it for reasons that aren't really relevant here). It seems to me that the instance I make using reflection should be identical in every way to the one passed in, and indeed I check the types and run DeepEqual to verify. Sadly, the created one behaves differently, and I don't know why.

Comment: @JohnSizemore I have provided two working examples of what I'm referring to. In doing so I caught a slight error that could be messing with your code. It has to do with taking the address of the underlying interface and passing it to unmarshal. Other than that I just re-orderd the testing order

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but you're caught up in the implementation details of a simplified snippet. I need a way, using the info available in LoadConfig (which does not include the definition of TestConf), to create a copy of the input parameter that acts exactly like the original. Reflection should be able to do this, and by every test I know the code above is the right answer. It just doesn't work. Even if I could inspect the two variables and detect they're different, I might be able to fix the issue. But the only way I know they're different is by submitting them to a third-party func.

Comment: The problem is you are passing a general interface reference to unmarshal. If you pass the pointer to the underlying type you should get the results that you expect.